# Java SimpleDateFormat gives different time zone for different day

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I had a strange behaviour when parsing dates. Given

```
DateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

`sdf.parse("25/10/2014")` returns 25 Oct 2014 00:00:00 **BST**

while

`sdf.parse("27/10/2014")` returns 27 Oct 2014 00:00:00 **GMT**

I figured out that's because of the Daylight Time change, but surely I would expect the same time zone to be returned by the same parser. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Your code examples are identical. Shouldn't there be 27 instead of 25 in second parsing example?

Comment: I recently ran across an [interesting discussion of gotchas in DateFormat](http://odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php) that might be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Wikipedia article on [British Summer Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time)

> During British Summer Time (BST), civil time in the United Kingdom is advanced one hour forward of Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), so that evenings have more daylight and mornings have less
>
> BST begins at 01:00 GMT on the last Sunday of March and ends at 01:00 GMT (02:00 BST) on the last Sunday of October.

The last Sunday of October 2014 was the 26th. So, the TimeZone changed from British Summer Time to GMT as observed in the UK.

The default TimeZone is your system TimeZone, so when that changes your parser will too.

Comment: I had already figured out that, as stated in the question. What you are saying would make sense if I were executing the code in different date (e.g. once before BST and once after).

Comment: @algiogia Because the date (an instant in time) isn't in BST. BST is called GMT on that date in your timezone.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `SimpleDateFormat#parse(String ParsePosition)`:

> The `TimeZone` value may be overwritten, depending on the given
>   pattern and the time zone value in `text`. Any `TimeZone`
>   value that has previously been set by a call to `setTimeZone()`
>   may need to be restored for further operations.

So: No, the parser does not always return the same time zone.

Comment: Well, I'm not setting any time zone.

Comment: @algiogia Then `System.out.println(sdf.getTimeZone());` gives you the system timezone. Because that is the default.